# Exchanging data between property page of CPropertySheet

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a property sheet having two pages. The first page contains an edit box (EDITBOX1)and a check box (CHECKBOX1) . The second page contains also contains an edit box(EDITBOX2) with a check box(CHECKBOX2).
I am trying to implement a way that when there is no value in EDITBOX1 and EDITBOX2 have some value CHECKBOX2 should be checked and it should be dithered .

Then when we entered somevalue to EDITBOX1 the previously checked CHECKBOX2 should not be checked and dithered.

Can anyone suggest me some implementation? Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Derive your own class from CPropertySheet.  Override CPropertySheet::OnActivatePage.  Set the appropriate page how you want when it is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Include your pages in your `MyPropertySheet.h` file. Declare your pages (`CPropertyPage m_Page1`, `CPropertyPage m_Page2`, ..) - as many as you need - in the `MyPropertySheet.h` file.

Add the pages to your `CPropertySheet` in the class constructor in `MyPropertySheet.cpp` file with method

```
CPropertySheet::AddPage(&m_Page);
```

Get parent of your `CPropertySheet` in `MyPropertyPage2.cpp` such as:

```
CMyPropertySheet* pSheet = (CMyPropertySheet*)GetParent();
```

Reach your `m_Page1` controls `pSheet->m_Page1.GetDlgItem(CHECKBOX2)` from `m_Page2`.